# How to extract specific data from website and store it into the sheet

Tags: json, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Im planning to have a list of the clan, something like this:

Player PlayerID Wins AverageCards

Player 1 #3G32DB4 343 5464

Player 2 #PP4V6SS 234 4512

...

Every clan can get up to 50 members. Im currently trying to get all player IDs and Names, to run my code for every member to collect data like this:

var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://royaleapi.com/data/player/cw_history/?player_tag=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");

I found these sources for clan ids:

https://www.deckshop.pro/spy/clan/89UJ8J2J

https://royaleapi.com/clan/89UJ8J2J

official game developer API, i tried it with that, but i needed some authorization. (https://developer.clashroyale.com/#/documentation)

What would be the easiest way to get like a list of all current clan members and run the code each member?

this is my current code for ONE SPECIFIC member, the plan is to run this for every member and build sums/averages. if you want to try it out:

```
function royaleapi() {

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://royaleapi.com/data/player/cw_history/?player_tag=29YY9L98C");
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  // Parse the JSON reply
  var json = response.getContentText();
  var data = JSON.parse(json);

  sheet.getRange(1,1).setValue("Rank");
  sheet.getRange(1,2).setValue("collection_day_battles_played");
  sheet.getRange(1,3).setValue("cards_earned");
  sheet.getRange(1,4).setValue("battles_lost");
  sheet.getRange(1,5).setValue("number_of_battles");
  sheet.getRange(1,6).setValue("wins");
  sheet.getRange(1,7).setValue("battles_won");
  sheet.getRange(1,8).setValue("timestamp");

  //start the loop
  for (var i=1; i<340; i++)
  {
    var rank = data["battles"][i-1]["rank"];
    sheet.getRange(i+1,1).setValue(rank);

    var collection_day_battles_played = data["battles"][i-1]["collection_day_battles_played"];
    sheet.getRange(i+1,2).setValue(collection_day_battles_played);

    var cards_earned = data["battles"][i-1]["cards_earned"];
    sheet.getRange(i+1,3).setValue(cards_earned);

    var battles_lost = data["battles"][i-1]["battles_lost"];
    sheet.getRange(i+1,4).setValue(battles_lost);

    var number_of_battles = data["battles"][i-1]["number_of_battles"];
    sheet.getRange(i+1,5).setValue(number_of_battles);

    var wins = data["battles"][i-1]["wins"];
    sheet.getRange(i+1,6).setValue(wins);

    var battles_won = data["battles"][i-1]["battles_won"];
    sheet.getRange(i+1,7).setValue(battles_won);

    var timestamp = data["battles"][i-1]["timestamp"];
    sheet.getRange(i+1,8).setValue(timestamp);
  }


}
```

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: What is exactly your issue here? You don't know how to run this for all the 50 members? Have you tried a for loop that calls you first loop (i.e iterate for each member and perform the for loop calculations for each of them)?